# How can I submit a form through a function?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function

First, I am using someone else's code (and I modified it to my use).
Second, I am new to VS Code. My normal editor is notepad++.

The confusing part is the way the syntax is highlighted. Makes me think there's an issue. I'm showing these images (instead of typing the code) so you can see the syntax highlighting I have.

[image]

notice `name` and `password` are blue? This makes me think they're being used as keywords. In notepadd++ they wouldn't appear this way. Also, this form isn't submitting the data. Here is how I am passing the information:

```
$user_id = $app->Register($yourName,$email,$username,$password);
$school_id = $app->RegisterSchool($user_id, $schoolName, $dbaName, $yourName, $rank, $email, $username, $password);
```

And yes, the form is passing the variables correctly. I echoed each variable to test.

Any help on what's going wrong is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "isn't submitting the data"... What **is** happening? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: & no idea about the syntax highlighting of password & I see some (like rank) are yellow. It does this to me too, and it's a little annoying sometimes, but i live with it.

Comment: It's all about the lint (an automated check so the syntax is correct in an early stage) that is used for your IDE.

Comment: @Reed No error message or nothing. Just submits the form and does nothing.

Comment: Make sure [errors are displayed](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=display%20errors%20php). I didn't know exit could accept a string. I always echo first then exit. You'll need to narrow down the problem if errors still don't output - put in echos & exits to confirm specific pieces of code are being reached. Var_dump some return values & make sure they're right. And do soms troubleshooting to make sure that your database is working, perhaps from CLI, then from PHP with a very simple `insert`. And maybe your INSERT is working but ypur SELECT query, elsewhere, is not.

Comment: I had to look at another website of mine for the solution. So, I noticed one difference. I didn't have this: ```$db = DB()``` so when I bound my values, I was previously passing an empty db connection.